# number of 5-digits numbers with no repeating digits bigger than 12345

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner in OCaml and algorithms.
I'm trying to get the number of 5 digits numbers with no repeating digits bigger than 12345.

Here is what I did in OCaml, I tried to make as tail recursive as possible, and I also used streams.  But still, due to size, it stack overflowed:

```
type 'a stream = Eos | StrCons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream)

let rec numberfrom n= StrCons (n, fun ()-> numberfrom (n+1))

let nats = numberfrom 1

let rec listify st n f=
  match st with
  |Eos ->f []
  |StrCons (m, a) ->if n=1 then f [m] else listify (a ()) (n-1) (fun y -> f (m::y))


let rec filter (test: 'a-> bool) (s: 'a stream) : 'a stream=
  match s with
  |Eos -> Eos
  |StrCons(q,w) -> if test q then StrCons(q, fun ()->filter test (w ()))
      else filter test (w ())



let rec check_dup l=
  match l with
  | [] -> false
  | h::t->
      let x = (List.filter (fun x -> x = h) t) in
      if (x == []) then
        check_dup t
      else
        true;;

let digits2 d =
  let rec dig acc d =
    if d < 10 then d::acc
    else dig ((d mod 10)::acc) (d/10) in
  dig [] d

let size a=
  let rec helper n aa=
    match aa with
    |Eos-> n
    |StrCons (q,w) -> helper (n+1) (w())
  in helper 0 a

let result1 = filter (fun x -> x<99999 && x>=12345 && (not (check_dup (digits2 x)))) nats



(* unterminating : size result1 *)
        (*StackOverflow: listify result1 10000 (fun x->x) *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your reported problem. When I load up your code I see this:

```
# List.length (listify result1 10000 (fun x -> x));;
- : int = 10000
# List.length (listify result1 26831 (fun x -> x));;
- : int = 26831
```

It's possible your system is more resource constrained than mine.

Let me just say that the usual way to code a tail recursive function is to build the list up in reverse, then reverse it at the end. That might look something like this:

```
let listify2 st n =
    let rec ilist accum st k =
        match st with
        | Eos -> List.rev accum
        | StrCons (m, a) ->
            if k = 1 then List.rev (m :: accum)
            else ilist (m :: accum) (a ()) (k - 1)
    in
    if n = 0 then []
    else ilist [] st n
```

You still have the problem that listify doesn't terminate if you ask for more elements than there are in the stream. It might be better to introduce a method to detect the end of the stream and return Eos at that point. For example, the `filter` function might accept a function that returns three possible values (the element should be filtered out, the element should not be filtered out, the stream should end).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the size of your stream `result1` is undefined.

Indeed, `nats` is an never-ending stream: it never returns `Eos`.

However, filtering a never-ending stream results in another never-ending stream
since a filtered stream only returns `Eos` after the underlying stream does so:

```
let rec filter (test: 'a-> bool) (s: 'a stream) : 'a stream=
  match s with
  | Eos -> Eos
  | StrCons(q,w) -> if test q then StrCons(q, fun ()->filter test (w ()))
      else filter test (w ())
```

Consequently, `size result1` is stuck trying to reach the end of integers.

Note also that, in recent version of the standard library, your type `stream` is called `Seq.node`.

Comment: Sorry, I thought result1 is finite after the filtering. So shouldn't it terminate?

Comment: No, the `filter` function has no way to know that `test` always returns false after the first 99999 elements of the stream. It thus keeps trying to compute one more element in result1.